# android - global layout refresh function

Tags: java, android

EDIT 2:
In my MainActivity I have a function (displayData) that displays the substitutions for my school.

```
public void displayData(List<Schoolday> results) {
    TabLayout mainTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTabLayout);
    ViewPager mainViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager);

    // draw the tabs depending on the days from the file
    mainTabLayout.removeAllTabs();
    for (int n = 0; n < results.size(); n++) {
        List<Subject> subjectsToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
        if (myPreferences.getBoolean(SHOW_WHOLE_PLAN, true)) {
            subjectsToDisplay = results.get(n).getSubjects();
        } else {
            List<Subject> tempSubjectsToDisplay;
            tempSubjectsToDisplay = results.get(n).getSubjects();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempSubjectsToDisplay.size(); i++) {
                if (tempSubjectsToDisplay.get(i).getCourse().contains(myPreferences.getString(CLASS_TO_SHOW, "None"))) {
                    subjectsToDisplay.add(tempSubjectsToDisplay.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        results.get(n).setSubjects(subjectsToDisplay);

        // only create a tab if there's any information to show within that tab
        if (results.get(n).getSubjects().size() > 0) {
            mainTabLayout.addTab(mainTabLayout.newTab().setText(results.get(n).getDate().substring(0, 6)));
        }
    }

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mainTabLayout.getTabCount(), results);
    mainViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    mainViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mainTabLayout));
    mainTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
```

This is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainTabLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the layout of the fragment that represents a page in the ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainSwipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever a refresh is triggered by the SwipeRefreshLayout I need the function displayData to be called. 
How can I call this function since the call comes from within a fragment/page from the ViewPager and displayData is not static?

Old question: 
I've been searching around quite a while but couldn't find an answer. Maybe I've searched for the wrong thing - just pointing me to that would already help.

My project ([Vertretungsplan on github](https://github.com/Crosswind/Vertretungsplan)) displays the substitution plan for my school which is available to view/download as an xml file ([xml file from school website](http://vplankl.gymnasium-beetzendorf.de/Vertretungsplan_Klassen.xml)). I then display the data in my app. 
I have a TabLayout (different tabs represent different days) and a connected ViewPager. Each page is using a fragment. Each fragment includes a RecyclerView (to display the results) which is wrapped in a SwipeRefreshLayout. 
When I want to refresh the data with the SwipeRefreshLayout I need to download all the data again and then update all the pages as well as the TabLayout(a new day might have a been added so a new tab will be needed). Since my refresh happens inside a fragment but I'm referencing the TabLayout as well as the ViewPager from my MainActivity I have no clue how to properly access all the elements in order to update the content.

My idea was to set up a Broadcast to let my MainActivity know that it needs to refresh the page since it originally set up the whole layout but maybe there is a better solution for that?

I'm kinda new to stackoverflow so feel free to correct me in the way of asking things here! If there's anything other information you need just ask me!
I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Since you are new, posting code is better than words to describe your question/problem. Also, try to make your actual question shorter - otherwise TL;DR

Comment: Did you try anything? Did it work? In order to get focused help on your problem consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I tried to be more specific with my edit! Thanks! @Jim!
I haven't coded anything (concerning the issue) because I have no idea what to do. My only idea was to use a Broadcast but I have no idea if that's suitable at all! @sdotdi

Comment: At this point, your question is still *very long* - maybe you should build "your bad idea" and then ask, "is there a better way to ...?" because it's still not clear what you want refreshed. You can store static variable, you can create interfaces, use `Activity` or `Fragment` methods, to communicate changes, and `Intent`s are also valid... or try re-wording your question (e.g. "How can I update the main content of my app?" - I can't tell what "main content" means... images? layouts? text? new fragment?)

Comment: I'm sorry that I keep bothering you. I tried again..maybe this time my issue becomes more clear? *hoping* @Jim

Comment: That was much more clear. Please see my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to implement what you are asking. The most direct way is to create an interface for the `Activity` that the `Fragment` uses. See the docs here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

The other option, which decouples the `Fragment` from the `Activity` (which some may see as an advantage) is to use an `Intent`. With that approach, you need to look into the `onNewIntent` method, as it is not obvious exactly how it works.

Either one should be fine, especially since you are exploring ideas at this point.

Comment: Thanks! Perfectly solved it for me. Hadn't paid much attention to interfaces just yet.